# uwsgi worker hangs on exit, but only if it used async trio module

Tags: python, django, uwsgi, python-trio

I have a Django site that uses the `trio_cdp` package to generate PDFs using a headless Google Chrome. This package is async, but my Django project is sync, so it has to run inside `trio.run()`

It's also using uwsgi locks so that only one client can generate a PDF at a time (headless Chrome loads the page in a single virtual tab, so it can only do one at a time)

Here is the code:

```
import trio
import base64
import requests
from django.conf import settings
from trio_cdp import open_cdp, page, target

try:
    import uwsgi
    have_uwsgi = True
except ModuleNotFoundError:
    have_uwsgi = False

async def render_pdf_task(url, params):
    r = requests.get(url=settings.CDP_URL)
    if r.status_code == 200:
        out = r.json()
        ws_url = out[0]['webSocketDebuggerUrl']
    else:
        return None
    async with open_cdp(ws_url) as conn:
        targets = await target.get_targets()
        target_id = targets[0].target_id
        async with conn.open_session(target_id) as session:
            async with session.page_enable():
                async with session.wait_for(page.LoadEventFired):
                    await page.navigate(url)
                await trio.sleep(0.5)
                pdf = await page.print_to_pdf(**params)
                pdfdata = base64.b64decode(pdf[0])
        await conn.aclose()
    return pdfdata

def render_pdf(url, params):
    if have_uwsgi:
        uwsgi.lock(1)
    pdfdata = trio.run(render_pdf_task, url, params)
    if have_uwsgi:
        uwsgi.unlock(1)
    return pdfdata
```

Annoyingly, any uwsgi worker that has run this particular task will later hang on exit until it is forcibly killed. If uwsgi runs and nobody visits the PDF-generating page, all the uwsgi workers exit fine. And it is consistently the uwsgi workers that ran the render_pdf function that need to be killed.

For example, pid 20887 had run render_pdf, and later when trying to shut down uwsgi, this happened:

```
SIGINT/SIGQUIT received...killing workers...
worker 10 buried after 1 seconds
worker 9 buried after 1 seconds
worker 7 buried after 1 seconds
worker 6 buried after 1 seconds
worker 5 buried after 1 seconds
worker 4 buried after 1 seconds
worker 3 buried after 1 seconds
worker 2 buried after 1 seconds
worker 1 buried after 1 seconds
Tue Jan 25 22:44:42 2022 - worker 8 (pid: 20887) is taking too much time to die...NO MERCY !!!
worker 8 buried after 1 seconds
goodbye to uWSGI.
```

How can I fix this? Any help is much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this myself. uWSGI's handler for `SIGINT` is overridden by `trio.run()`, but only if `trio.run()` is in the main thread. I solved this by running it in another thread.